# Definition for "emergency lever"

Tags: word-meaning

I've got another definition (for a noun) to write, this time for "emergency lever" (again, no defs found in dictionaries).
Is

> A lever to be actuated in case of an emergency situation, for
>   example to turn off a machine or stop the movement of a vehicle.

an accurate definition?

Comment: I think that's splendid.

Comment: A lever meant to shut down operation in case of emergency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lever whose movement is designed to provide a benefit in an emergency situation, for example through turning a machine on or off, starting or stopping the movement of a vehicle, or opening something to provide access or escape.

Answer (score 1):

> A lever to be **activated** in case of an emergency situation, for example to turn off a machine or stop the movement of a vehicle.

[image]